# Google Maps giving null pointer while loading

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in android currently doing a project where am implementing google maps on a blank activity. I have been getting a frustrating null pointer exception when loading google maps in my app. For now, i have tried everything i know.
In my values folder, i have an xml.

**google_maps_api.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">My_api_key</string>
</resources>
```

**Map_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_map_main">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.2.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

}

**Map_main.java file**

```
public class MapMain extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_main);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
 Unable to start activity `ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemaps/com.example.googlemaps.MapsMaon}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference`
```

Comment: Well that sounds like `findFragmentById` is returning `null`. There are lots of questions about that.

Comment: go for this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

Comment: remove .. `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: and replace with what

Comment: with nothing.. and remove the ( . ) also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

`android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment‌​"`

in layout, instaed of

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

Comment: findFragmentbyID now me an error- cannot resolve method

Comment: show me the code snippet after removing the `getSupportFragmentManager`.

Comment: Ohhh... my mistake i think... you should put the previous code there.. and use `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` in layout instaed of `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`.

Comment: welcome... i have updated my answer, so that it could be helpful to someone else in future.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Extend it with `FragmentActivity` rather than `AppCompatActivity`